Apt update throw error in Ubuntu 24.04
I have just installed Ubuntu 24.04. When i try to run "sudo apt update" it throws the below error.
I have tried:

changed "Download from" server from main to other server in software & updates. But it still shows the same error.
run sudo apt upgrade before update
checked proxy in network setting and it is off
I am using wifi connection so i changed dns from wifi connection setting to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 but it didn't help so i changed back

Error:
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease                                                          
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease                                                                         
Ign:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease                                                                         
Err:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble Release                                                                       
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.82 80]
Err:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates Release                                                              
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.82 80]
Err:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security Release                                                            
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
Err:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports Release                                                            
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.82 80]
Hit:9 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                       
Reading package lists... Done                   
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

sources list
Here is my sources list (cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources)
Types: deb
URIs: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
Suites: noble noble-updates noble-backports
Components: main restricted universe multiverse
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg

Types: deb
URIs: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
Suites: noble-security
Components: main restricted universe multiverse
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg

System Information
uname -a
Linux habib-Latitude-E6410 6.8.0-31-generic #31-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sat Apr 20 00:40:06 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

dpkg --print-architecture
amd64

lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble


Is this machine on a restricted network that is filtering traffic (ie. letting some thru & blocking traffic that is unknown) such as a school, corporation etc. Your details read like a network issues to me (ie. DNS functioned, but then traffic was blocked..)  Alternatively you're using an incorrect repositories for your unstated architecture; but that would require you to have incorrectly modified your sources/mirror...

i am using home router and i tried to change dns but still same error. i have updated question with system architecture details (x86_64) and sorry i didn't understand last part of your comment

This looks like a network problem. Those mirrors work.

Selecting Best Serever from software & update solved the issue. The download server was changed to "mirrors.cloud.tencent.com/ubuntu".

But the below nobel-security release issue was still there.
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease                    
Err:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security Release                                          
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.82 80]

So i commented code for security URIs and added "nobel-security" to the top Suites. Here is updated code of ubuntu.sources
Types: deb
URIs: https://mirrors.cloud.tencent.com/ubuntu/
Suites: noble noble-updates noble-backports noble-security
Components: main restricted universe multiverse
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg

#Types: deb
#URIs: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
#Suites: noble-security
#Components: main restricted universe multiverse
#Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg


I initially thought signing up for ubuntu PRO would help with these "repository disabled" errors. It did not, but the solution described here (selecting best server, then commenting/editing ubuntu.sources) solved the problem when followed precisely. Thank you.
